# ToolTip не стандартной формы - C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет! 
Подскажите как сделать TootlTip нестандартной формы?
Например чтобы он при наведении на кнопку курсором мыши всплывал и был не просто прямоугольный, как он по умолчанию.
А например имел вид:
Типа что то вроде "клювика" чтобы у него был, или указателя

```
_____________
|           |
|           |
|________  _|
         \/ 
       кнопка
```

И всплывал он не под кнопкой, а над кнопкой, чтобы "клюв" как бы на кнопку указывал

Comment: Думается мне, надо писать свой всплывающий виджет, наверное я бы в этом случае смотрел в сторону QML

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, а в чем тут преимущество qml?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb в возможности более гибко настраивать поведение всплывающих подсказок и их геометрию. Хотя в случае обычного тултипа без анимаций пожалуй можно и без QML